# Eslint is throwing `no-undef` while destructuring in a for..of loop

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am using eslint and a little bit of customized airbnb standard.

My eslintrc file,

```
module.exports = {
  extends: 'airbnb-base',
  rules: {
    'no-restricted-syntax': 'off', // allow for..of loop
  },
};
```

This is a sample loop which have destructuring too.

```
for ({ bar: foo, baz: fiz, biz } of data) {}
```

Eslint is throwing error,

```
'foo' is not defined. (no-undef)
'fiz' is not defined. (no-undef)
'biz' is not defined. (no-undef)
```

Is doing this inside `for...of` anti-pattern?

The problem is that it is throwing error no matter how I define it. The only way to avoid this was,

```
for (const sample of data) {
  let { bar: foo, baz: fiz, biz } = sample;
}
```

I do not want to disable `no-undef` because it is very important for other areas of the program. However I could not find a resource or explanation regarding this behavior.

Could it be because I disabled no-restricted-syntax and airbnb does not have the correct rule for this kind of behavior?

Out of curiousity, I browsed thru the repo and found some interesting issues,

- [Using 'ForOfStatement' is not allowed (no-restricted-syntax)](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1271), however I disabled this rule, so it doesn't apply here.

Comment: What if you do `let foo, fiz, biz` on one line then do the destructuring assignment?

Comment: The other rule is that `Split 'let' declarations into multiple statements. (one-var)`. Which means I will have to write let three times for that.

Comment: Ah...in that case, you might want to try doing an in-line declaration to disable the `no-undef` rule and then enable it afterwards. To be honest, this seems like a bu in the ESLint parser but I'm trying to come up with ways around it.

Comment: If that's the case, I can just use the workaround that I wrote at end of my question. But I want to get into this problem and know why it is doing this. Thanks for helping anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `const` or a `let` before the destructuring.
Try this:

```
for (let { bar: foo, baz: fiz, biz } of data) {}
```

That seemed to have solved it for me.